# Why does initializing Canvas globally cause error after first frame in dart, flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

I am trying to make this codepen more readable for the sake of understanding it.
https://codepen.io/creativecreatorormaybenot/pen/RwrEQoe

If I initialize canvas inside `onBeginFrame` function, the code works fine.
[image: when canvas is initialized inside function]

But if I initialize canvas globally outside the function, only first frame works and then I get this error
[image: error image]

Is it not efficient to have the Canvas object global because it can be reused across the loops? Thanks for your answers.

I'm new to dart:ui level so I haven't tried anything else to solve the issue.